# Parameter passed via http post from an android app is not being received in the php script

Tags: php, android

I tried different solutions that has already been answered here for similar questions, but its not working. help me find the error in these codes below.

android side

```
Button b2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttons3);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                     //String test="hello";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.1/prosample.php");

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", "hello"));

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Execute and get the response.
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {

            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }
    });
```

//php

```
    <?php
      $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
      if(!$conn) die("unable to connect to MYSQL:".mysql_error());
      else echo "connected to the server" ;
      mysql_select_db("proj",$conn);// or die("Unable to select database",mysql_error());
      $hello = $_POST['test'];
      echo $hello;  

      $query = "INSERT into pro(colmn) values ('$hello')";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
      else echo "AWESOME!!!!";
    ?>
```

i found that, the parameter passed is not being received in "test" here . . , because the string "hello" that i entered in android and passed via 'test' is not being inserted into the table pro which is in the db "proj".
how do i solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let this answer be useful to the one's who may face this issue. There is nothing wrong with the code.
The problem was with the use of wamp server and connectify in the same system, while trying it in a local host.